# RFHutilc disable OCSP check

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

In RFHUtil client,  do we disable OCSP check and how? as getting below error

Intially getting "Remote SSL certificate revocation status check failed for channel"
Then after adding
Entry in mqclient.ini file

```
SSL:
  OCSPAuthentication=OPTIONAL
  OCSPCheckExtensions=NO
  CDPCheckExtensions=NO
```

After adding this entry , getting error as the channel did not supply any certificate

Comment: If you need to disable it you should look at the SSL stanza of the mqclient.ini.

Comment: If add any entry for ssl in mqclient.ini, the error changes that the client didn't send any certificate . Seems it doesn't take the settings from rfhutilc after there is an entry made for ssl: in ini file.

Comment: Update the question with the full SSL stanza you added.

Comment: @JoshMc have update the details in the question

Comment: What is your cert label?

Comment: Added the cert label entry and its working after that. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT15978

Comment: That is what I was going to suggest if it was not a standard label. You should write a quick answer with you SSL stanza so others will know how to fix it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certlabel entry is mandatory for rfhutilc to connect to queue manager which uses certificates.

```
SSL:
     AllowTLSV13=TRUE
     OCSPCheckExtensions=NO 
     CDPCheckExtensions=NO
     OCSPAuthentication=OPTIONAL
     CertificateLabel=myclientcertname
```

Comment: Certlabel is only mandatory if your label does not match the standard label expected by IBM MQ, this is `ibmwebspheremq<lower case username>`, so if you are running the program as a user called `user1929905`, the standard label expected is `ibmwebspheremquser1929905`.  I would also suggest you provide an example of the SSL stanza you used in the answer.